# Getting error Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Genres' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Using entity framework code first approact to insert data into a table by the following command:

```
public partial class PopulateGenresTable : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Melody')");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
```

The Genre has the code like:

```
public class Genre
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Defined as:  `public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }`

And when I tried to run the command `update-database` getting the following error. Can you tell me where I am doing wrong?

```
PM> Update-Database
Value does not fall within the expected range.
At C:\Projects\GigsHub\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:977 char:5
+     $DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.BuildProject($configuration, $project ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

Value does not fall within the expected range.
At C:\Projects\GigsHub\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:977 char:5
+     $DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.BuildProject($configuration, $project ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [201606252031479_PopulateGenresTable].
Applying explicit migration: 201606252031479_PopulateGenresTable.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Genres' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:b8a869e0-e2da-4fcb-8ccb-624307ad7b98
Error Number:544,State:1,Class:16
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Genres' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Comment: Sounds like the table in the database is set up to auto-generate the value of the `id` attribute on insert and doesn't allow an explicit value to be specified.

Comment: So, What is the steps to solve this? The table definition looks like: 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Genres] (
    [Id]   TINYINT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Genres] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);'

Comment: IDENTITY is auto increment and therefore won't accept explicit values. Either remove the keyword and re-build your database or set DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity on this column.

Comment: I just noticed: IF you set DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity on this column, use EF functionality to create the insert statements for you, or drop the id value.

Answer (score 2):

Following Mosh's course? Me too. I basically did this:

```
Sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Genres ON");
Sql("INSERT INTO Genres (Id,Name) VALUES(1, 'Melody')");
Sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Genres OFF");
```

Comment: I just got this answer from Mosh: https://twitter.com/moshhamedani/status/762623941303230464
The problem should go away if a byte is used instead of int for the Id column. (yes!)

Comment: And what about other entities referring to `Genre`? I think it's not the right approach to use any specific data type *only* for avoiding an identity column to be generated. That's what mappings are for. Mind you, now there can't be more than 255 genres.

Comment: Yeap,, this is the way to go. Also, bravo for Mosh and his courses!